# Processing JSON Data within Oracle APEX v4.2

Tags: javascript, json, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have the following code within a JavaScript dynamic action in Oracle APEX v4.2 to work with JSON, i.e.:

```
var graph_data = $v('P780_GRAPH_DATA');
var rule_data = $v('P780_RULE_DATA');

var unique = function(origArr) {
  var newArr = [],
      origLen = origArr.length,
      found, x, y;

  for (x = 0; x < origLen; x++) {
    found = undefined;
    for (y = 0; y < newArr.length; y++) {
      if (origArr[x] === newArr[y]) {
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!found) {
      newArr.push(origArr[x]);
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}

    var accessLines = graph_data.filter(function (line) {
      return !isTrunkLine(line);
    });
    var trunkLines = graph_data.filter(isTrunkLine);

    accessLines.forEach(drawLine);
    trunkLines.forEach(drawLine);


    function isTrunkLine(intf_type) {
      var purpose = intf_type.purpose;

      return purpose === 'TRUNK';
    }
```

When working with this outside of Oracle APEX but just in a separate HTML file that contains the javascript code, all works fine but now having to move this into Oracle APEX, I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: graph_data.filter is not a function
```

Unsure what I am doing wrong but I basically have a valid JSON object within graph_data as I have run it through JSONLint but not sure what the issue is here.

Comment: What does `$v('P780_GRAPH_DATA')` return? It should be an array.

Comment: @Tom I actually construct my own JSON via a select statement where I enclose this inside the square "[" and "]" brackets so looks like it's a string. Basically a function call that returns a VARCHAR2. How can I convert to an array pls?

Comment: How do you get this string? Through an ajax call?

Comment: Using a function call that returns a string in this format: select '{'
                  || ' "id" : "'|| id  || '"'
                  || ',"node" : "' || node || '"'
                  || ',"node_name" : "' || node_name || '"' etc

Comment: Sorry, I probably wasn't clear enough. You're constructing this string in sql, but somehow are passing it along to Javascript. For example, so you have an Ajax call prior to this code which communicates with an on-demand process which returns this through htp.p? Or are you using some other means of passing this data along. It might help in determining the most efficient solution. If it's in code prior, could you add it?

Comment: Just in a DA - javascript, which I have now made a change to convert to a JSON object, I do the following: var my_graph_data = $v('P780_GRAPH_DATA');
var graph_data = $.parseJSON('[' + my_graph_data + ']'); but when I attempt to call my isTrunkLine(intf_type) function I am now getting the following error: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column. Does this mean that the DA javascript region editor is too long?

Comment: The parse is correct. It now ensures you have an array, and now filter will work. Previously you had a string, and filter is an array function. I was asking about Ajax because it could've been just a simple datatype return setting. I don't understand the new error though. When are you receiving this? It's a plsql error, so it has nothing to do with the Javascript code I'd expect.

Comment: When I press "Apply Changes" within the DA JavaScript editor - any ideas? Is the size of my JSON object to big within editor? Really unsure what is going on here and it has me a bit worried. Do I need to process the JSON side of things differently?

Comment: It could very well be your DA has become too long. How many characters are you at, over 32k?

Comment: I'm using Oracle APEX v4.2 and I think the limit is 4000. As it's JavaScript I have in my DA, can I place these into static files within Shared Components or perhaps you may have another suggestion?

Comment: Files are always good. But in this case you can just wrap your code in a function, put it on the page under "Global variables and functions", and then call the function in your DA javascript code.

Comment: Thanks, will try that but will I still experience any limitations within Global Variables and Functions?

Comment: gulp - good question. Can't say I've run into that myself, though I can't say if I've ever stored that much code there. Either way, a file is the fallback then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end with Tom's assistance, I simply forgot to parse my JSON object and also hit a limitation within Oracle APEX v4.2 of 4000 characters for a DA.

Please see: http://www.explorer-development.uk.com/avoiding-dynamic-action-plsql-length-limit/

I had to rearrange my JavaScript code, which was a nuisance. It's all fine now.